# How to use PRISM within C# windows service applications?

Tags: c#, windows-services, prism, prism-4

I'm trying to create an windows service application which i would be able to add modules in it as we do in WPF and Silverlight.
This is how i went throw :

```
public static class Program
{
    public static string CurrentAppPath { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        Program.CurrentAppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(
             System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

        ShellBootstrapper bootstrapper = new ShellBootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();
    }    
}
```

And for the ShellBootstrapper class :

```
class ShellBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        DirectoryModuleCatalog directoryCatalog = 
          new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = Program.CurrentAppPath };
        return directoryCatalog;
    }

    protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return null;
    }        

    public override void Run(bool runWithDefaultConfiguration)
    {
        base.Run(runWithDefaultConfiguration);

        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new MyService(logger)
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }        
}
```

Are there any sample out there?

Comment: These snippets seem to be okay. What are you missing? The only thing I'd change would be to remove the `new MyService` and let prism resolve that - use the `Container` property and `Resolve<T>` to get your service with all dependencies.

Comment: Were you able to get your service to run? I have yet been unsuccessful, and I'm using EventAggregator and Unity in my Service.

Answer (score 1):

lock at [this](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/). you can download there sample as you can see in picture

After download and installing prism(v4), in root directory you have folder named as `stock trader`. that's what you need! (run desktop version). In section Modules you can Find folder named `service`.

This is simple, you can call Wcf-service in these method right here.(also you can use wcf method as async-service )

Comment: Hi Rev, the link give a lot of samples for Silverlight and Windows desktop but has no Windows-Service examples for prism.